# Разделение текста в PHP

Tags: php

Добрые вечер, у меня проблема, есть IP который я хочу разделить на 2 элемента, IP и PORT только вот я не могу понять как это сделать, почитал пару статьей но так и не понял, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$address  =  '127.0.0.1:8080';
$parts = explode(':', $address);

if(count($parts) !== 2) {
    throw new \Exception("Error address format");
}

list($ip, $port) = $parts;

echo sprintf('IP: %s, PORT: %s', $ip, $port); //IP: 127.0.0.1, PORT: 8080
```